# Trying to disblay a xml embedded image (base64 encode) in a browser with CSS

Tags: css, xml, base64

i am a little nooby in XML/CSS. So i have no idee is it posible what i try.

I have a xml-doc (base64.xml). In this file is a base64_encode PNG image and a reference to a css-file.

Now i try to display the embedded image in a browser and style it with CSS. But the image wont display.

Ok lets go: I have a xml-doc (base64.xml). In this file is a base64_encode PNG image and a reference to a css-file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="base64.css"?> <root>

<image mime="image/png">iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADcAAAAqCAYAAAAXk8MDAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAABQSURBVGhD7c8xEcAwEMCwTzmUc1mnS0goZy2evb5591zqOb1Sc6rmVM2pmlM1p2pO1ZyqOVVzquZUzamaUzWnak7VnKo5VXOq5lTNqZozzfxwSwHwD/dUzwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
</image>

</root>
```

If i open this xml with a browser (chrome, firefox), i see the ASCII-string and the Browser says something is overflow: (http://localhost/base64.xml)

`iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADcAAAAqCAYAAAAXk8MDAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAABQSURBVGhD7c8xEcAwEMCwTzmUc1mnS0goZy2evb5591zqOb1Sc6rmVM2pmlM1p2pO1ZyqOVVzquZUzamaUzWnak7VnKo5VXOq5lTNqZozzfxwSwHwD/dUzwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==`

If the xml-file have no css reference, it shows the content of the file.

What else I'm trying to do to display the image:

1. I add a inlne css statement. But this is only working with html/css. Not with xml/css.

xml-file:
`<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADcAAAAqCAYAAAAXk8MDAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAABQSURBVGhD7c8xEcAwEMCwTzmUc1mnS0goZy2evb5591zqOb1Sc6rmVM2pmlM1p2pO1ZyqOVVzquZUzamaUzWnak7VnKo5VXOq5lTNqZozzfxwSwHwD/dUzwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="/>`

no css-file.

2. I definenated a class and a style attribute-var. Works with hmtl/css. Not with xml/css.

xml-file:
`<div class="test" style="--bg-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADcAAAAqCAYAAAAXk8MDAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAABQSURBVGhD7c8xEcAwEMCwTzmUc1mnS0goZy2evb5591zqOb1Sc6rmVM2pmlM1p2pO1ZyqOVVzquZUzamaUzWnak7VnKo5VXOq5lTNqZozzfxwSwHwD/dUzwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==')"></div>`

css-file:

```
.test {
  width: 525px;
  height: 252px;
  background-image: var(--bg-image);
}
```

3. I try a parameter transfer with a tag in the xml and the var(), attr() funtion in css. completely not work.

xml-file:
`<p data-foo="iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADcAAAAqCAYAAAAXk8MDAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAABQSURBVGhD7c8xEcAwEMCwTzmUc1mnS0goZy2evb5591zqOb1Sc6rmVM2pmlM1p2pO1ZyqOVVzquZUzamaUzWnak7VnKo5VXOq5lTNqZozzfxwSwHwD/dUzwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="></p>`

css-file:

```
:root {
  --temp: attr(data-foo);
}

p {
  width: 525px;
  height: 252px;
  background: url('data:image/png;base64,var(--temp)');
}
```

What else can I try?